# OrderByRaw in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making an app that filters products

I want to add this query chunk to my `$products = $products-> newQuery();`

I'm using `$products = $products-> newQuery();` Because I am querying with filters. Example:

```
$products = $products->newQuery();

  if ($request->has('brand') && !empty($brand)) {
            $products->where('brand', '=', $brand);
        }

        if ($request->has('size') && !empty($size)) {
            $products->whereHas('stocks', function($query) use ($size) {
                $query->where('size', '=', $size);
            });
        }
```

I want to add this query

```
 $best_sellers = OrderItem::select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity) DESC')->limit(2)->get();
```

I have previously used it in another method and it works but I don't know how to integrate it

I tried:

```
$products->whereHas('order_items', function($query) {
                        $query->select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity) DESC');

});
```

But it hasn't worked

Any idea? thanks

Updated with Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `with()` to add relationship data `whereHas()` it just for filter it does not add new key

example

```php
$products->with(['order_items'=> function ($q) {
    $q->select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity) DESC')->limit(2)->get();
}]);
```

Comment: If i do:  `$products->whereHas('order_items', function($query) use ($size) {
                        $query->select('product_id',\DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as order_sum'))->groupBy('product_id')->orderBy('order_sum', 'DESC');
                    });` the same thing happens when i do `$products->whereHas('order_items', function($query) {
                        $query->select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity) DESC');

});` It only returns the products sold, but does not add the sale quantity or order them

Comment: So how can I integrate it? I need the OrderItem table and be able to add it to `$products`, so a query like `$order = OrderItem:: ...` doesn't work for me

Comment: Ok i tried: `$products->with('order_items', function ($query) {
                            $query->select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->orderByRaw('SUM(quantity) DESC');
                        });` (Because with [ ] i got a code error) but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @jagcweb i made it array to fixed that code error

Comment: Hi, still not working. It does not make any changes to the products with that query